# IIS Caching Deleted SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am using IIS 10 on Windows 2016

Whenever I update my SSL certificate and apply that to binding IIS doesn't use that but keeps using the old certificate.

Things what I have tried till now -

1. Restart website
2. Restart App Pools
3. Restart IIS
4. Deleting old certificate from IIS /Windows store

> Rebooting Windows does solve it everytime.

Comment: Here same, too. Only a reboot helped.

Comment: In [this article](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple/wiki/HTTPS-Binding-With-Specific-IP#resolution) they write "_…you may have to wait for the Application Pool's Idle Timeout time is reached. Restarting or recycling the Application Pool/ IIS/ Server will not change the certificate. Only waiting for the Idle Timeout time will change the certificate…_" — So maybe waiting is sometimes the only option.  

Answer (score 1):

If you have a firewall or Load Balancer, you will need to install the certificate there too. had same issue and that was the fix.